# How to Output JSON value to DOM using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

This might be a stupid question, but I'm a noob who's been looking into this all day yesterday and today and having trouble finding a clear answer.

I am having issues isolating the value from a single key:value pair in a JSON API call. In my code below, I am trying to make a call to  a locally hosted JSON file and want to GET the value of "maxFileSize".

The JSON being called would look something like the following {"maxFileSize" : "10MB"}. I want to GET the value using the object key "maxFileSize" and append it to my div tag in my HTML. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="randominfo"></div>

<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON('http://localhost/MISREST/images', function (data) {
      $.each( JSON.parse(data), function ( key, val ) {
        $("#randominfo").append(data.maxFileSize + " "); 
    });
});



});


</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the C# code generating the JSON data. The JSON is renamed to MISREST/images in another C# file:

```
    public string JSONGetImageFiles()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(SmSystemConfig.ImageFilePath))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(SmSystemConfig.ImageFilePath);
            FileInfo[] fileEntries = dir.GetFiles();
            StringBuilder toReturn = new StringBuilder("");

            toReturn.Append("{\"maxFileSize\" : \"10 MB\", \"fileList\" : [");

            if (fileEntries.Length != 0)
            {
                int count = 0;
                foreach (FileInfo file in fileEntries)
                {
                    if (file.Extension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || file.Extension.ToLower() == ".png" || file.Extension.ToLower() == ".gif")
                    {
                        count++;
                        toReturn.AppendFormat("{{\"fileName\" : \"{0}\", \"href\" : \"{1}{2}\",", file.Name.Remove(file.Name.LastIndexOf(".")), SmSystemConfig.ImagePath, file.Name);
                        toReturn.AppendFormat("\"uploadDate\" : \"{0}\",", file.CreationTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                        toReturn.AppendFormat("\"fileSize\" : \"{0}\"}},", GetFileSize(file.Length));
                    }
                }
                if (count != 0)
                    toReturn.Replace(",", "]}", toReturn.Length - 1, 1);
                else
                    toReturn.Append("\"None\"]}");
            }
            else
            {
                toReturn.Append("\"None\"]}");
            }
            return toReturn.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription = "Directory Not Found";
            return "{ \"errorMessage\" : \"generror\" }";
        }
    }
```

C# File where API paths are defined (this is the section where the images filepath is defined):

```
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "images",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    string JSONGetImageFiles();
```

Comment: The response of $.getJSON is a plain object.  Won't $.each(data,... work?

Comment: It's multiple objects in one call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try referring to the `val` that's being passed as function argument within the `each` function:

```
$.each( JSON.parse(data), function ( key, val ) {
   $("#randominfo").append(val.maxFileSize + " "); 
});
```

Comment: And what does a `console.log(data)` before the `each` function prints?

Comment: {"maxFileSize" : "10 MB", "fileList" : [{"fileName" : "1_Exterior 
     Cabinet_Cabinet C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat", "href" : 
      "../Images/1_Exterior Cabinet_Cabinet 
      C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat.jpg", and the JSON continues

Comment: Yep, your fiddle seems to work but the same code isn't working on my end. I added the C# code that populates the JSON data above for reference

Comment: I'm not able to talk about C#, but I think the main issue is in the way you're trying to access to `data` check if it's well formatted.

Comment: I managed to get it to work just using console.log(val) instead of console.log(val.maxFileSize). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

It's not totally clear to me which of these is the case, but based on your C# code and your comment on the answer above, your JSON file is either a single object (meaning `.each` is not needed to access data within it) or it's a series of objects without any delimiters between them (meaning `JSON.parse` should be throwing an error.)

Assuming a single object, you would get the maxFileSize like so:

```js
var data = '{"maxFileSize" : "10 MB", "fileList" : [{"fileName" : "1_Exterior Cabinet_Cabinet C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat", "href" : "../Images/1_Exterior Cabinet_Cabinet C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat.jpg"}]}';

$('#go').click(function() {
  $("#randominfo").append(JSON.parse(data).maxFileSize + " ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="go">Go</button>
<div id="randominfo"></div>
```

Assuming what you're really trying for is an array of objects, the JSON needs to be structured as an array, and when iterating through that array you need to be referring to each object inside the array instead of to the parent `data` like you're doing:

```js
var data = '[{"maxFileSize" : "10 MB", "fileList" : [{"fileName" : "1_Exterior Cabinet_Cabinet C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat", "href" : "../Images/1_Exterior Cabinet_Cabinet C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat.jpg"}]}, {"maxFileSize": "20MB", "fileList": []}]';


$('#go').click(function() {
  $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, val) {
    $("#randominfo").append(val.maxFileSize + " "); // <-- not data.maxFileSize
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="go">Go</button>
<div id="randominfo"></div>
```